# Numbers uneven in some font-sizes

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

I have had this issue a few times with webfonts. The numbers tend to have uneven height in some font-sizes and are more even in others.

In the .gif below I am switching between 21-23px.

[image: Switching between 21px and 23px font size]

Is there a better solution to this then just notching the font size up/down a px?

- Now I am using Source Sans Pro nut I have had this before with other fonts.
- This seems to be a cross browser issue (on windows at least)
- I have to host this font myself, but the problem didn't exist when I used google fonts
- Maybe it's just my feeling... but I think uneven px-sizes tend to render nicer.

**EDIT** (I got asked for some font css):

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.svg#source_sans_probold') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-italic-webfont.svg#source_sans_proitalic') format('svg');
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.svg#source_sans_proregular') format('svg');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro-semibold-webfont.svg#source_sans_prosemibold') format('svg');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;

}
```

Comment: The description is quite good but we would like to see your CSS font rules.

Comment: Not just numbers. And not just webfonts. Several of the fonts that are officially in the Linux repositories look that sloppy in selected font sizes. It's something you can either live with, or you'll have to choose another font.

Comment: @MrLister I was afraid I would get this answer :) But do you have an idea why this problem didn't occur when I fetched the fonts from google fonts?

Comment: @LeopoldKristjansson Ehm, Google fonts are _good_ fonts? I don't really know, I'm sorry. Some fonts are designed by amateurs, some are hinted manually, others by running automatic hinting routines, some fonts were made by converting from one format to another. There are so many different factors.

Comment: modern browser note: SVG fonts are no longer supported, whereas everything supports WOFF (have a look at http://caniuse.com for which browser cross section support which technology). All you need in those @font-face rules is the WOFF resources, and *maybe* the eot, if you're the kind of person who wants to keep enabling out of date browsers on operating systems that Microsoft no longer even supports.

Answer (score 2):

What did you use to generate your WOFF file? Because if I take the .otf Source Sans Pro, convert it to WOFF with FontCreator, and load it in with the simplest of CSS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Source Sans Pro WOFF test</title>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: ssp;
        src: url('SourceSansPro-Regular.woff');
      }
      body {
        font-family: ssp;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">0123456789</p>
    <p style="font-size: 21px">0123456789</p>
    <p style="font-size: 22px">0123456789</p>
    <p style="font-size: 23px">0123456789</p>
    <p style="font-size: 24px">0123456789</p>
    <p style="font-size: 25px">0123456789</p>
    <p style="font-size: 26px">0123456789</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I get the following results:

[image]

All of these look aligned identically to what it does in desktop publishing software, so it looks very much like your "webfont" version has been ruined by whatever software you used to convert the font for web purposes.

Even if I use the Google hosted version of Source Sans Pro, things look just fine: http://jsbin.com/vajoxesudo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I am going to try your method. However, I didn't convert the font. I just downloaded it from Google Fonts. Here: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro

The google hosted version also looks good when I tried it. The problem started after I downloaded the font and started hosting myself.

Comment: stop using all the different flavours. Just use the `.woff` with the super simple syntax first, see if that fixes your problem. If so: it's not the `.woff` and you can either stop caring, or go through the possible font files to see which one's responsible for bad rendering. Debug one problem at a time.